# Inner = {Property = true} compiles, is that a compiler bug or a misused Feature?

Tags: c#-4.0

I just stumbled upon something that's got me scratching my head.  Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, I accidentally assigned a property an object without providing the new operator or a type and it compiled, but threw an exception upon execution.

Here's an example of what I was doing:

```
public class Outer
{
    public Inner Inner { get; set; }
}

public class Inner
{
    public bool Property { get; set; }
}
```

Instantiation of new Outer:

```
var outer = new Outer
{
    Inner = {Property = true}
};
```

I would expect to see a compiler error in this case, but this is compiling successfully.  So, is this a bug or some new feature I've stumbled upon that I'm just not using correctly?

Comment: If it's a bug it's already in VS 2010.

Comment: Well `var outer = new Outer().Inner.Property = true;` would compile too

Comment: Yes, but this syntax makes sense because Inner could be initialized to a new instance of Inner by Outer's constructor.  Nothing unusual going on there.

Comment: Surely the same is true for the initialiser syntax, your initialiser instantiation code is exactly equivalent to: `Outer temp = new Outer(); temp.Inner.Property = true; var outer = temp;`

Comment: As it turns out, the code example I provided does compile if Outer initializes Inner within it's constructor.  So you're correct in equating the syntax I've stumbled upon with the explicit initialization.  So the question is, does this represent some type inference feature that's been introduced at some point?  I'm aware of type inference for generics and the var keyword, but I haven't seen this kind of type inference in C#.

Comment: Interestingly, while the above syntax works, you can't do something like: outer.Inner = { Property = true };  It only works if it's nested within the initialization of another class.  This seems inconsistent if it was actually a intended feature.

Comment: The example I added is exactly how initializers are compiled (via a temp variable for atomicity), as in compile them both and the emitted IL is the same - so I think its just an artifact of that